Jpa specification filtering troubles
Let's say I have two related tables t1 and t2 with the relation oneToMany and I want to create a utility class that will filter by the entered value and the field of the dependent table if field matches value then we get t1 with related entity that matches and if there are no matches related entities or null we just get t1 with empty list of t2.
Example if field in t2 matches value:
{
        "id": 1,
        "title_t1": "test title t1",
        "t2": [
            {
                "id":1,
                "title_t2":"test title t2",
                "isActive" /*field we entered*/ :true  /*value we expected*/
            }
        ]
//if there are other related t2 entities they don't match expected value we entered
    }

Example if there are no entities with field that matches expected value or null:
{
        "id": 2,
        "title_t1": "test title t1 v2",
        "t2": []
// t2 is empty because there are no related entities(null) or all related entities not matches expected value
}

I wrote this static method and it works correct but when there are t1 where all related entities t2 not matches expected value entity t1 not include, i know that it doesn't include because such entities not match any of my criterias, but i can't solve this problem to reach expected output data
   public static <T, E, V> Specification<T> hasAssociatedEntityWithField(
            ListAttribute<T, E> joinField, SingularAttribute<E, V> filterField, V value
    ) {
        return (root, _, cb) -> {
            Join<T, E> join = root.join(joinField, JoinType.LEFT);

            return cb.or(
                    cb.equal(join.get(filterField), value),
                    cb.isNull(join.get(filterField))
            );
        };
    }


You should modify your expectations. If T1 has a List of T2s, when you fetch T1 you are expected (and should expect!) to get its full list of T2s with it. You are fetching a managed entity from the database that reflects the data as it exists there. Your filtering is only used to figure out which T1s to get and should not modify the data itself. If you want a separate list of T2s that match a filter, query for them separately, or apply your filter to the collection associated in the T1 yourself after it returns
